# Overriding the back button

Tags: java, android, overriding, onkeydown

I have this code for overriding the `back` button and making it act like the `home` button:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

It is working perfectly.  My question is if there is one location I can put this to make it work for all activities.  Right now I have this method replicated in every activity.

Comment: It's not a good idea to do such things. Users will be confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own BaseActivity and extend it with Activity, override back there. Now in your whole app instead using Activity use that BaseActivity.

Something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity 
{
    final protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    onCreate_Impl(savedInstanceState);
   }

   abstract protected void onCreate_Impl(Bundle savedInstanceState);
}
```

You have to use onCreate_Impl in place of onCreate.

Answer (score 3):

Create a base activity, handle the key there and inherit all your other activities from your base activity.

Comment: @Ascorbin, I need to type more quickly :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a BaseActivity (extends Activity) with this code, then let all your Activities extends BaseActivity, not Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can make some abstract class, which extends Activity and implements this method.
Then subclass it in every Activity of your app. Only one class can be extended at a time, but in most cases, this is a good idea to have some abstract Activity class containing some common functions for a set of application activities.